# Is there an easy way to change one value in a nested json data with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, operators, spread-syntax

TypeScript version: ^3.5.3

For this json

```
const config = {
  id: 1,
  title: "A good day",
  body: "Very detailed stories"
  publishedAt: "2021-01-20 12:21:12"
}
```

It can be changed to a new title with spread syntax as

```
const newConfig = {
  ...config,
  title: "A new day"
}
```

The final `newConfig` data will be

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: "A new day",
  body: "Very detailed stories"
  publishedAt: "2021-01-20 12:21:12"
}
```

---

But in this case

```
const config = {
  id: 1,
  articleConfig: {
    version: "2",
    configs: [
      {
        title: "A good day",
        body: "Very detailed stories"
        publishedAt: "2021-01-20 12:21:12"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Also want to change `title`'s value. Tried

```
const newConfig = {
  ...config,
  articleConfig: {
    configs: [
      {
        title: "A new day"
      }
    ]
}
```

It will break the pre-defined json schema:

```
const newConfig: {
    id: number;
    articleConfig: {
        version: string;
        configs: {
            title: string;
            body: string;
            publishedAt: string;
        }[];
    };
}
```

So is there an easy way to overwrite only one item in this kind of json?

Comment: rember that json is javascript. and in javascript objects are mutable. no need to complicate things with immutable style copying.

Comment: TypeScript's version is `^3.5.3`. So what do you mean how to make a new data base the current one?

Comment: i wonder why everything is const. you could clone the object and mutate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const oldConfig = { /* ... */ };

const newConfig = {
  ...oldConfig,
  articleConfig: {
    ...oldConfig.articleConfig,
    configs: config.configs.map(config => ({
       ...config,
       title: "A new day"
    }))
};
```